# Wordpress auto adds p to shortcode parameters

Tags: shortcode

Wordpress auto adds p tags around shortcode parameters. Is there any way to stop this ?

```
function minimum_working_example ( $atts, $content ){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'html' => '',
    ), $atts));

    return '<span data-html="'.$html.'"></span>';
}
```

shordcode call:

```
[min_example html='<ul>stuff</ul>']
```

what ends up being rendered:

```
<span data-html="

<ul>stuff</ul>
<p>"></span>
```

desired output is something along the lines of:

```
<span data-html="<ul>stuff</ul>"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure that your shortcode functions are executed *before* wpautop by changing its filter priority.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```